Custom card only displays if hovered two or more consecutive times
I have a simple list with a gallery view.

I edited the JSON formatting to add a custom card to be displayed when the item is hovered over. All I changed was adding the customCardProps to the first div - the one with the sp-card-defaultClickButton class, which covers the entire item.
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/tile-formatting.schema.json",
  "height": 143,
  "width": 254,
  "hideSelection": false,
  "fillHorizontally": true,
  "formatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "attributes": {
      "class": "sp-card-container"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "sp-card-defaultClickButton"
        },
        "customRowAction": {
          "action": "defaultClick"
        },
        "customCardProps": {
          "formatter": {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-lastTextColumnContainer"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "p",
                "attributes": {
                  "title": "[$Description]",
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary sp-card-content  sp-card-multiline"
                },
                "txtContent": "=if ([$Description] == '', '–', [$Description])",
                "style": {
                  "-webkit-line-clamp": "2",
                  "height": "40px"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "openOnEvent": "hover",
          "isBeakVisible": true
        }
      },
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "ms-bgColor-white sp-css-borderColor-neutralLight sp-card-borderHighlight sp-card-subContainer"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-displayColumnContainer"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "p",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary sp-card-label"
                },
                "txtContent": "[!Title.DisplayName]"
              },
              {
                "elmType": "p",
                "attributes": {
                  "title": "[$Title]",
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary sp-card-content sp-card-highlightedContent",
                  "role": "heading",
                  "aria-level": "3"
                },
                "txtContent": "=if ([$Title] == '', '–', [$Title])"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-lastTextColumnContainer"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "p",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary sp-card-label"
                },
                "txtContent": "[!Description.DisplayName]"
              },
              {
                "elmType": "p",
                "attributes": {
                  "title": "[$Description]",
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary sp-card-content  sp-card-multiline"
                },
                "txtContent": "=if ([$Description] == '', '–', [$Description])",
                "style": {
                  "-webkit-line-clamp": "2",
                  "height": "40px"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}


However, the card only displays if I hover over an item two or more consecutive times. If I hover over an item once, it does not display. If I hover over the item a second time, it displays. If I hover over item 2, then item 1, then back to item 2, it does not display on either item. How do I get the card to display every time I hover over an item?
